# Selenium in VBA - Asynchronous Use?

Tags: vba, selenium, asynchronous

I've written some code based on simple examples that downloads and then parses a couple of webpages. I'd like to speed things up though, and at the moment both the parsing and the downloading of the sites are both taking a few seconds.

The below is what I have, and it currently seems to wait for each line to finish before continuing:

```
Sub Demo ()
   Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, PageCollection As WebElements, searchTerm As Variant
   Dim Success As Boolean

   Searches = Array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")

   For Each searchTerm In Searches
      driver.Get "http://somesite/Search.aspx?ppid=100&QueryExpr=" & searchTerm

      Set PageCollection = driver.FindElementsByClass("upperContainer")

      Success = parse(PageCollection)
   next searchTerm

end Sub
```

What I'd prefer to do is to set the browser off doing it's thing, parse  the last page it found, and then wait if the browser still isn't ready... Does anyone know how? Pseudocode below:

```
Sub Demo ()
  Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, PageCollection As WebElements, searchTerm As Variant
  Dim Success As Boolean, i as Integer

  Searches = Array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")

  driver.Get "http://somesite/Search.aspx?ppid=100&QueryExpr=" & Searches(0) 

  For i = 1 to UBound(Searches,1)

      Set PageCollection = driver.FindElementsByClass("upperContainer")

      driver.GetAsync "http://somesite/Search.aspx?ppid=100&QueryExpr=" & Searches(i) 'NOT A REAL COMMAND

      Success = ripitems(PageCollection)

      'GUESSWORK!
      While driver.busy 'NOT REAL
        DoEvents
      Wend
  next searchTerm

end Sub
```